# Angular2 ngAfterViewInit() invoked on parent first

Tags: angular

I have a parent component & child component with templates as shown below respectively:

```
@Component({
selector : 'my-app',
template :  `<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row page-header">
        <span class=" col-lg-1"></span>
        <img class="img-responsive col-xs-2" src="./app/EF Education First Logo_tcm25-388033.jpg" alt="logo"/>
        <h1 class="txt-primary col-xs-9">Issues Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="col-xs-1"></span>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <tree-view #tree class="treeview" [treeData]=treeData ></tree-view>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 well content">
            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <comments-section></comments-section>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

</div>`,
providers:[WebApiService]
```

})

Child component(recursive):

```
@Component ({
selector: 'tree-view',
template: `<ul>
                <li *ngFor="let node of treeData">
                    <a (click)="onDateSelect($event)" href="#">{{node.name}}</a>
                    <tree-view *ngIf="node.subnodes" [treeData]="node.subnodes" ></tree-view>
                </li>
            </ul>`
```

})

When i put ngAfterViewInit() in both parent & child i get the following logs(i have put logs inside)
[image: Logs data]

The same things happens when i use ngAfterContentInit() which is quite surprising to me. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: I'm confused what the issue is. The parent view fires `ngAfterContentInit` before all the children are complete?

Comment: @Adam Yes, you are right!

Comment: Without full relevant code it is difficult to guess.